# Facebook Ads API through FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-ads-api

Facebook offers an API for ads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/

In the docs they only describe how to do requests through the graph API. Are there correspondent FQL tables as well? I'd like to use querying: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

Answer (score 1):

The tables you see via the [FQL Table List](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) are the only current connections provided. There's 3 ad tables currently there. If those aren't what you need, then FQL simply isn't possible right now. Maybe in the future, but not right now. Use the Graph API. There's a considerable amount of documentation available for [Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/) (which is just a subset of the Graph API) too

Comment: At the table list I only see adaccount_offsite_conversion_event table, which isn't what I'm looking for. The thing is that I already have some prebuilt stuff for FQL, so it would be easier to just use that..doesn't seem to be possible though. Thanks for the answer.